# Display a User Control From Another User Control MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I currently have this method in my view model which is triggered when the user clicks on a grid row:

```
    public ICommand EmailPopUpCmd { get; set; }
    private void EmailPopUp(object sender) {
        //ToDo: pdf viewer pop up
        var test = sender;
        var email = new EmailView { DataContext = new MailVM() };
        email.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

The user control I want to display looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Sybrin.UI.MailViewer.Views.EmailView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:fixed="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Fixed;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.FixedDocumentViewers"
         xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Converters;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.FixedDocumentViewers"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sybrin.UI.MailViewer.Helpers"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         DataContext="{Binding}">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:BoolToDisplayConverter x:Key="BoolToDisplayConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.25*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <telerik:RadToolBar DataContext="{Binding ElementName=pdfViewer, Path=CommandDescriptors}">
        <telerik:RadToolBar.Resources>
            <converters:FixedDocumentViewerModeConverter x:Key="ModeConverter"/>
        </telerik:RadToolBar.Resources>
        <telerik:RadToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding FixedDocumentViewer.Mode, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ModeConverter}, ConverterParameter=Pan}"
                                 Margin="2"
                                 Padding="0"
                                 IsBackgroundVisible="False"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                 >
            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                <TextBlock Text="Pan" />
            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Telerik.Windows.Controls.FixedDocumentViewers;component/Images/hand-free.png"
                   Stretch="None" />
        </telerik:RadToggleButton>

        <telerik:RadToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding FixedDocumentViewer.Mode, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ModeConverter}, ConverterParameter=TextSelection}"
                                 Margin="2" Padding="0"
                                 IsBackgroundVisible="False"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                <TextBlock Text="Text Selection" />
            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Telerik.Windows.Controls.FixedDocumentViewers;component/Images/text-selection.png"
                   Stretch="None" />
        </telerik:RadToggleButton>
    </telerik:RadToolBar>
    <telerik:RadPdfViewer x:Name="pdfEmailViewer"
                          Grid.Row="2"
                          DocumentSource="Sybrin.UI.MailViewer;Resources/TestPDF.pdf"/>
</Grid>
```

Now the above method does not display my user control.  Any ideas as to why not?

Comment: Where are you trying to display this user control?

Comment: Like a pop up (almost like a message box)

Comment: You are just creating an instance of the user control and switching the visibility. I cannot see it being added to the view anywhere.

Comment: How would I add it to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should open this User Control in other Window.

Take a new Window and add this User Control to that view (in xaml). Then create an instance of that Window in your button command handler and just using Open() method of window should do job.

Window myWindow = new Window();
myWindow.Open();

This is not a very good MVVM way though!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the user control to the xaml view where you want it to be displayed and keep the visibility bound to a property. Let the value be collapsed at the beginning. Change it to visible when you want the control to be visible.

eg:

```
<Grid>
   <EmailView Visibility= "{Binding ControlVisibility}" />
</Grid>


public ICommand EmailPopUpCmd { get; set; }
private void EmailPopUp(object sender) {
    ControlVisibility = Visible;
 }

 private Visibility _controlVisibility = Collapsed;

 public Visibility ControlVisibility
 {
    get
    {
       return _controlVisibility;
    }
    set
    {
        _controlVisibility = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ControlVisibility");
    }
 }
```

Make sure that you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the visibility change to reflect in the UI

Comment: I tried this, but I think the Visibility.Collapsed and Visibility.Visible should be assigned via a converter (since the error I'm getting now is: `Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'UI.MailViewer.ViewModels.MailVM' and 'System.Windows.Visibility'. Consider using Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=; DataItem='MailVM' (HashCode=48386891); target element is 'MailViewerView' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')`

Comment: Are you sure you go the right `DataContext` on your `EmailView`? The error seems to be because you are trying to bind a property of type `MailVM` to the visibility.

Comment: MailVM is the view model to which both the display grid (in code:     `public partial class EmailView : UserControl {
        public EmailView() {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MailVM(); //binds data context to the mail model view
        }
    }`

Comment: Hmm... This error indicates a type mismatch in the binding. I guess this shouldn't occur if a property of type visibility is bound to the visibility of the control.

Comment: Also please check if you have used `Mode = TwoWay`

Comment: I did add `Mode=TwoWay` but it still does that... I agree though, it wouldn't make sense that it needs a converter in the first place.